# Is their a NoSQL in .NET that can inform my application if the document has changed?

Tags: mongodb, redis, couchbase, ravendb, nosql

I'm looking for a NoSQL that has .NET API (key-value or document db) that can raise an event in my aplication when a document/entity has been changed (created, updated or deleted).

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDB has a [Changes API](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/changes-api), which can inform you about document changes.